# Passing parameters to OData service initialization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, odata

I got an OData service implemented using .NET core, which has this part in its initialization n the startup.cs file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  try
  {
     app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
     {
        ...
        routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(
                        routeName: "name",
                        routePrefix: ModelConstants.RoutePrefix,
                        configureAction: containerBuilder =>
                        {
                            ...                
                           containerBuilder.AddService<IODataQueryProcessor>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(DefaultODataQueryProcessor));
                        ...
     }
```

How can I pass parameters here to `DefaultODataQueryProcessor` which has a constructor with parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below codes :

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
                     routeName: "name",
                     routePrefix :"aaa",
                      configureAction: containerBuilder => {
                          containerBuilder.AddService<IODataQueryProcessor>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, serviceProvider => {
                              return new DefaultODataQueryProcessor("someString");
                          } );
                      }

                 );

        });
```